# Wordpress: Display "Edit Profile" link to author only

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I have a WordPress website with a custom theme.  I'm using custom author template page to display a public "profile" of the user's page.  I want to show a link to the edit page (I have a template for that too) to ONLY the logged in user who is also that particular author.

I have the following code, but it shows the edit link to ALL logged in users.  I don't want users to think they can edit other authors' profiles.

```
<?php global $user_id, $user_login; 
get_currentuserinfo();  
$author_id = $curauth->user_id; 

if($user_id !== '' && $author_id == $user_id){
    echo 'EDIT LINK HERE';
}
```

?>

Comment: Anything under 50% i leave. Take you .2 seconds to click the check mark, takes us minutes to type an answer.

Comment: How am I supposed to mark an answer as Accepted if it is never answered correctly or enough to have made it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there.  Don't worry about the global variables, they'll just mess things up.  What you want is this:

```
<?php
if(get_query_var('author_name')) :
    $curauth = get_user_by('slug', get_query_var('author_name'));
else :
    $curauth = get_userdata(get_query_var('author'));
endif;

get_currentuserinfo();

if( $curauth->ID == $user_ID) {

    // Do your edit link work here ...

}
?>
```

This first loads the current author based on the query variable used to generate the author profile page.  That's how you get `$curauth->ID`.  Then it loads up all of the standard information for the current user (see [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo) for a full list of the variables populated by `get_currentuserinfo()`).  Then it does a simple comparison between the two values ... no need to check that `$user_ID` has a value, because a null value for that variable won't be equal to `$curauth->ID` anyway.

FWIW I've tested this on WP 3.0.1 and you should be good to go.

Comment: That's a fair defense, and I won't hold that against you :-)  In the future, you can always offer a bounty on your question.  That will pop it to the top of the list and get you several more answers (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty).  Or ask on the new WordPress Answers StackExchange instead (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com).